# Query based on where clause of linked results from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables in my database. Table A is what holds the main ID and title of a project. Table B is the main details table of the project and we record a new record for every update made on it. Table C is for the divisions which can be added to a project and there can be more than one for each record.

**Table A**

```
TAID | Name
-------------
1   |  Test 1  
2   |  Test 2  
3   |  Test 3
```

**Table B**

```
TANo   |   TAID   |   Description   |  Completed
------------------------------------------------
1      |   1      |   Some text     |  True
2      |   1      |   More text     |  True
3      |   1      |   Extra text    |  False
4      |   2      |   Other text    |  True
5      |   2      |   Test text     |  True
6      |   3      |   Text          |  True
```

**Table C**

```
DivID   |   TANo   |   TAID   |   DivisionID
------------------------------------------------
1      |   1      |    1      |   1
2      |   1      |    1      |   2
3      |   2      |    1      |   2
4      |   3      |    1      |   2
5      |   6      |    3      |   4
```

What I am after is I want to write a query which will let me pull out the latest record of an ID but broken down by division(s). I've got my query to just get the latest row from Table B to Table A but I'm stuck as to how I can query my results based on say I want to get all results for Division 1? Or multiple divisions?

```
 Select 
 ta.Name
,tb.TANo
,tb.TAID
,tb.Description
,tb.Completed
From
TableA ta

CROSS APPLY
(
    Select
    Top(1)
     b.TANo
    ,b.TAID
    ,b.Description
    ,b.Completed
    From
    TableB as b
    Where
    b.TAID = ta.TAID 
    Order by b.TANo desc
) as tb
```

So as an example I could have this record which has had multiple updates to it:

**Table A**

```
TAID | Name
-------------
2   |  Test 2
```

**Table B**

```
TANo   |   TAID   |   Description   |  Completed
------------------------------------------------
4      |   2      |   Other text    |  False
5      |   2      |   Test text     |  True
```

**Table C**

```
DivID   |   TANo   |   TAID   |   DivisionID
------------------------------------------------
3      |   4      |    2      |   2
4      |   5      |    2      |   2
5      |   5      |    2      |   4
```

Then with adding something to my above query if I searched on records that were in divisions 2 and 4 I could pull back results where it just shows the latest single record of a project

**Result**

```
TAID   |   TANo   |   Description   |   Completed
------------------------------------------------
2      |   5      |    Test text    |   True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent record in `tableb` for each division, you can join and use window functions fo filtering:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.divisionId, 
        b.description, 
        b.completed, 
        row_number() over(partition by c.divisionId order by tano desc) rn
    from tablec c
    inner join tableb b on b.tano = c.tano
) t
where rn = 1
```

Of course you can also bring in `tablea`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.divisionId, 
        b.description, 
        b.completed, 
        a.name
        row_number() over(partition by c.divisionId order by tano desc) rn
    from tablec c
    inner join tableb b on b.tano = c.tano
    inner join tablea a on a.taid = b.taid
) t
where rn = 1
```

Note: it is unclear why you are storing `taid` in both `tableb` and `tablec`; as far as concerns, a record in `tableb` belongs to a single project, so there is apparently no need to store redundant information in `tablec`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Fair point I could remove TAID from TableC as I can use just TANO as my join. 

This query has almost worked but it doesn't seem to bring back everything? Also it is showing a record for all updates made to TableB and extra records if there's multiple divisions against a record.

What I am after is say for example TableB might have multiple updates (meaning multiple division updates) I just want to be able to say search on records for Division ID 1 and 2 it would just show the single latest record. I've updated my question with some more details.